# OpenCV stitching with georeferencing

Tags: opencv, geocoding, image-stitching

Is it possible to create stitched image without loosing image position and geo-referencing using OpenCV?

For example I have 2 images taken from the plane and I have 2 polygons that describes where on the ground they are located. I am using OpenCV stitching example. OpenCV stitching process will rotate and change position of images. How can I preserve my geography information after stitching? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!